# Why is my container wider than its child in other browsers than Chrome?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I need some help. While I was working on a project in Chrome, I wanted to test it in Firefox and was puzzled as to why it looked so different.

[image: Screenshot from Firefox]

Can anyone explain to me why the green div containing the image doesn't adjust its width relative to the child? Is it a bug? Is it a feature? Is it a bugfeature?

### Research

It works, as I expect in Chrome, where it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot from Chrome]

But in Firefox, there is a lot of weird white space (this is the same image as the first):

[image: Screenshot from Firefox]

Also, here is a screenshot of the following browsers (starting from the left) Firefox, Opera and Internet Explorer 11:

[image: Screenshot from FF, Opera and IE11]

As you can see, it works like I expect in Opera, but not in FF and IE11. It doesn't work in Edge either.

### My findings

It looks to me like Firefox forgets to recalculate the parent's width after the image has been resized.

Here is a screenshot without height constraints (100% of the parents 200px height):

[image]

If I readd the height constraint, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the width is the same. Note that the green div's width is 510px. That is the the same as the image (500px) + the padding (5px + 5px).

### The code

I tried to add a jsFiddle, for your convenience, but curiously, I were not able to reproduce the error there (it worked as it was supposed to).

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <style>

        .wrapper {
            height: 200px;
        }

        .div1 {
            float: left;
            background-color: green;
        }

        .div1 img {
            height: 100%;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        .div2 {
            background-color: blue;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="div1">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
        </div>

        <div class="div2">
            <h1>Heading</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'll answer my own question in hope of helping someone else*

### TLDR:

I was missing the HTML5 doctype declaration, which looks like this: `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

### Longer version:

While writing this question, it suddenly struck me that it could be caused by the lack of a doctype declaration. A quick test confirmed my suspicion. All I was missing was the `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration!

It's safe to say that I'll update my snippet to include a doctype. I used Visual Studio's `doc` snippet and never gave it another thought. Note that the `html` snippet already includes a doctype. (In VS: If you type `html` or `doc` and hit tab in an HTML document, a quick HTML template will appear)

#### Why

Without a doctype declaration, the browser renders the page as best it can, in the so called *quirks mode*. In quirks mode the browser has to guess how the page is supposed to look with **primary focus on backwards compabillity**. Therefor the result naturally deviates from newer specifications.

The doctypes was invented to differentiate legacy sites from those using newer specs back when IE and Netscape was a thing. You can read more about it on MDN here:

- [Doctype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Doctype)
- [Quirks mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode)

Nice to know:

> Make sure you put the DOCTYPE right at the beginning of your HTML document. Anything before the DOCTYPE, like a comment or an XML declaration will trigger quirks mode in Internet Explorer 9 and older.

-MDN

> In HTML5, the only purpose of the DOCTYPE is to activate full standards mode.

-MDN

#### How to see which mode is being used

On Windows, click `alt` to bring up the good old toolbar, then go to `Tools` ➡ `Page info`

[image]

[image]